# После миграции на AndroidX цвет hint в EditText стал белым для android sdk < 25

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, androidx

Вот мой EditText:

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
   android:ems="10"
   android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
   android:hint="@string/email"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:paddingLeft="40dp" />
```

После миграции на Android-X текстовые подсказки в полях ввода стали белого цвета для устройств которые < 25 API level.

Подскажите плиз в чём может быть проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте ваш layout-файл и через DesignMode в панели Attributes у атрибута textColorHint посмотрите откуда он берет цвет. Потом просто создаете свою тему(сли своя уже есть, то не надо) и переопределяете в ней android:textColorHint. Если не важно, то можно просто у каждого EditText переопределить этот же параметр.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня 3 модуля и для каждого прописан foreground_material_light color - он белый. Как я понял до api 25 он подтягиваеться для hint атрибута, а после api 24 не подтягиваться..Но это всё произошло после перехода на AndroidX..

Comment: @МаксимШимко возможно гугл внес изменения в тему, либо сама тема сменилась на другую. В любом случае, отследите тему, откуда этот параметр тянется и переопределите либо в своей собственной теме(на базе необходимой), либо просто все время назначайте вручную в EditText. Лучше используйте первый вариант, чтобы раз и навсегда установить нужный textColorHint.